# What are ISS orbit's sudden falls?

Tags: iss, orbit

In current (2021) graph from heavens above (https://www.heavens-above.com/IssHeight.aspx) there are sudden falls - more than 1km in many cases and then after other sudden changes, the graphs return on path of previous almost smooth decay:

[image: iss orbit height for 2020 and 2021]

For example in the middle of April 2020, middle of July and beginning of October 2020.

Those are not present in older ISS height graphs, for example:
[image: iss orbit height for 2017 and 2018]

I understand what sudden jumps up are (engine boosts), and what "slow" falling is (orbit decay).

What I don't understand are those sudden falls of 1-2km in less than one day apparently.

What are those?

Comment: After the jump up in March 2020 and the following jump down in April the ISS is at the same slope as before. Just imagine a straight line drawn from February to May.

Comment: Also notable is that the current graph is on average ~15km higher than just a few years ago - I wonder what prompted that change?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Until 2011 the orbit was intentionally low to allow a larger payload for the Shuttle. The current higher orbit reduces drag and fuel consumption.

Comment: @asdfex Yeah, but we're not talking about pre-2011 here.  The 2nd graph there is 2017-18.  Has something significantly changed between then and now?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman 2012-2014 they were at the same height as now. 2014-2018 was a slight bit lower.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What caused the ISS's sudden loss of altitude in January 2015?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12636/what-caused-the-isss-sudden-loss-of-altitude-in-january-2015)

Comment: @MaxQLagrange That does explain why it went down around 2014, but still not why it went back up again in 2018.

Comment: **not a duplicate!**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They've done a few "de-boost" burns to set up orbital phasing for an upcoming visiting vehicle rendezvous from time to time.  That's likely what you're seeing.

Edit: looking at the first plot -- I'm not necessarily sure this is the case now.  Notably, the "de-boosts" in that first plot bring the altitude right back to the decay trajectory it was on previously.  And the shape of the mean altitude spike in the September-October timeframe looks suspiciously similar to the March-April one.  This has me wondering if it is in fact a data or a calculation problem and not reflective of what ISS was actually doing.

All that said, de-boosts *have* been utilized to set up phasing in the past.

Comment: There's a "Soyuz phasing reboost" mentioned in this April 2020 report, but no details https://blogs.nasa.gov/stationreport/2020/04/page/18/

Comment: A reference would improve this answer.

Comment: Haven't found anything public in recent memory -- only internal ops notes.  Edited my post with more thoughts now.

Comment: These do remind me of orbit solution instabilities due to correlations between fitting parameters. I think there has been previous discussion of this effect, I'll go look. If there are any documented de-boosts, they could serve as answers to [How often has (or how common is it for) the ISS's orbit been propulsive lowered intentionally?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33125/12102) If there's even *a likely timeframe* when one may have happened then I can go look trough TLEs for a sustained change.

Comment: **update:** It seems that [(at)BowlOfRed's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40026/12102) mentions two or three times there was a retrograde or de-boost burn. It seems its only possible when there's a docked spacecraft with extra propellant and the engine pointing in the right direction. As for correlations in fitting parameters, see my answers to [Did Tiangong-1 turn the engines on?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24710/12102) and [PSLV-C39/IRNSS-1H TLE accuracy](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24047/12102)

Comment: `bring the altitude right back to the decay trajectory it was on previously`  Well, yes, that's what *phasing* is all about.  On the same trajectory as before, but now displaced in *time*.  Having spent time in a higher orbit, briefly, the station will be later arriving at the same point over the earth some time in the future.

Comment: @uhoh For practical purposes, there's almost always a progress vehicle docked to SM aft which does the reboost/deboost maneuver IIRC.  Pointing the engine in the right direction is just a matter of maneuvering station as appropriate. (They prefer to use the progress thrusters whenever possible instead of station's thrusters, as thrusters are limited life items)

Answer (score 18):

I had a thought about inaccuracies of orbit estimation like @uhoh...

But I then asked - what changed since 2018 (the lower picture of OP)?

Two major changes:

1. a [crewed Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Dragon_2#Crew_Dragon)
2. [Soyuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_(spacecraft)) and [Progress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_(spacecraft)) spacecraft have switched to a 3-hour flight scheme.

After comparing launch dates, it's clear that the second is the reason.

It requires much more precise orbits phasing than previous schemes of Soyuz/Progress.

If we look at the upper graph - we see orbit fall in April, and [Soyuz MS-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_MS-16) was launched April 9, 2020.

Then falling in July - [Progress MS-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_MS-15) was launched July 23, 2020.

Falling in October - [Soyuz MS-17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_MS-17) was launched October 14, 2020.

In comparison, Crew Dragon doesn't require such precise orbit phasing because it currently (2020) uses longer flight scheme.

Comment: This might be a coincidence. Why would you do that three times in a way that puts the station back to the extrapolated decaying height? For a pure phasing change that wouldn't be necessary - and it happens three times during the year.

Comment: @asdfex: A boost followed a whole number of orbits later with a matching deboost is exactly what you'd need for a pure phase change. It will put you back in your original (or originally predicted) orbit, but delayed by some amount that depends on the size of the boost and how long you spend in the boosted orbit. As for why there are two boosts and one deboost, I don't know, but maybe they wanted to start with an initial boost and observe its effects for a while before following up with a second one to hit the exact desired phase shift.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Right. Actually, it's a bit more complicated. In April they raised the perigee and lowered the apogee to get into an almost circular orbit. In September there was a raising of perigee and apogee separated and a combined lowering.
https://heavens-above.com/OrbitHeight.aspx?satid=25544

Comment: Another change is that the ISS is 20 km higher than it used to be, so the decay rate is lower.